Python reading from a file. Skip empty lines and comments
I'm in a introduction course for Python. I am having a hard time understanding how Python works. I am up to the 6th chapter and each time I find myself setting variables with unintended results but if I switch VarA to where VarB is located. Switch positions, amazingly the program works as intended.
counter = 0
with open(text, "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line.isspace() == False:
        counter += 1

This so far counts how many lines there is and skips over the empty lines. I try to check for a comment # line using startswith() but that yields a error to the point isspace() is no longer working. I have tried nesting startswith().
I try putting startswith() in it's own if it counts twice as much. I tried setting counter -= 1 in this if block alone. It yields a error.
Beyond showing me 5 hours of more videos. I really do not understand how startswith() is a function from Python and some how it does not work in the place where you put it.
Every two problems I need to solve that this course introduced, I am constantly rearranging locations of variables and functions. Asking how does a pre-built function fail to respond or be recognized at line 40 of a program. Some computers just guess intended results.
I have tried nested, I have tried putting one function in front of the other. I don't understand how Python fails to reach it's built in functionality.

Can you post at least one example of the non-working code? We can't guess at what you got wrong without a [MCVE]. Your existing code is distinctly unidiomatic (e.g. if line.isspace() == False: should be if not line.isspace():, and if you put your loop in the with block, you could delete lines = file.readlines() and change the for to for line in file: to reduce memory usage and improve performance; file.readlines() is basically never needed), but it works, we need to know what you actually did wrong to offer fixes and explanations.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but there's no question here. More importantly, it's not clear what the problem is. line.startswith('#') should work; is that what you were using? Show the code with the problem, don't just vaguely describe it. See [mre]. Secondly, save the ranting; it doesn't help you get an answer. For more tips, see [ask]. You can [edit].

It's clear that you're a bit frustrated with how and why things aren't working; you should provide clear examples of problems you have trouble solving, or share changes to code that have result that were unexpected to you, and ask specific questions about it.

You don't have to specifically check for true/false.  You can just say if line.isspace() or if not line.isspace()

You are very close to counting lines that are not spaces or comments... change the line
   if line.isspace() == False: 
to
   if line.isspace() == False and not line.startswith('#'):
Python is an interpreted language which means each line is run as soon as it is submitted, roughly speaking. You can use this to help you test out things before you try them in your code.
For example, you have successfully read in lines from your file. so you can investigate the lines one at a time by typing lines[1] in the python interpreter. then you can test out the startswith() function by doing something like lines[5].startswith('#') and you will get back True if there is a '#' at the start of the line and False otherwise.
This is a typical way you can learn Python and code at the same time.
I understanding learning a new thing can be frustrating but stick with it. As you pick up new tricks that help you like the stuff I mentioned above you will get better and before you know it... you know Python:)

I solved this by moving the locations around:
counter = 0
    for line in lines:

        if line.isspace() == False:
            counter += 1
        if line.lstrip().startswith("#") == True:
            counter -= 1

You cannot call lstrip() after for line in lines:. Neither will
if line.isspace() == False or line.lstrip().startswith("#") == False:

work correctly over the server the Online School Course provides.
The original program I wrote on VisualCode worked just fine. And continued just fine when I rearranged  locations. It seems over some variations of interpreters, this school course interpreter demands lstrip() at the right position. Also, you cannot do line.startswith("#").lstrip().

Your test used the wrong conjunction. It would have worked just fine with and instead of or, though it's still unidiomatic to compare to False, so if not line.isspace() and not line.lstrip().startswith("#"): counter += 1 (or alternatively, if not (line.isspace() or line.lstrip().startswith("#")):) would be the more idiomatic phrasings.


Skip empty lines and comments

Try below code:
with open(text, "r") as file:
    counter = 0
    for line in file:
        if not line.isspace() and not line.startswith("#"):
           counter += 1


not line.isspace() would already exclude the line == '\n' case, so line != '\n' is a pointless addition.
